# Colouring map based on numeric value in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I have a question related to **R**. I'm trying to colour the area for different countries on a map based on a numeric value. Now, I don't have the values for all country, so some of them will be empty.

```
Year    Country       Numeric
2009    Afghanistan
```

Like this. So when I get values based on a certain level such as >5, 5-10, etc. I want to fill them with different colours. How can I do that in **R**? I've spent quite a long time on this without making significant headway.

I can fill in the world map, but can't manipulate it for the data I have.

```
> p <- ggplot(world, aes(long,lat,group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill="darkgreen",colour="white") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightsteelblue2"))
```

Any advice and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `fill` as part of your `aes`:

```
library(maps)
world<-map_data("world")

set.seed(123)
w2<-data.frame(world,data=sample(10,length(unique(world$group)),T)[world$group])

ggplot(w2,aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=data))+
    geom_polygon(color="white")+
    scale_fill_gradient(low="lightgreen",high="darkgreen")+
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightsteelblue2"))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks real good. I'm gonna give that a go. One thing that you might be able to help me with that I can't seem to find in the documentation. Supposing my data has missing countries, what can I do to state those countries as having invalid or a NA value with some colour?

Comment: You can specify the color for NA values in the color gradient, for example     `scale_fill_gradient(low="lightgreen",high="darkgreen",na.value="black")`.  If you want the "NA" to show up in the legend, that's trickier.

Answer (score 3):

You could use rworldmap (which has the advantage of having a modern map including e.g. S.Sudan and excluding e.g. Soviet Union). Maps are available at 3 resolutions (the default is the coarsest suitable for global maps.

```
library(rworldmap)

#example data including an NA
country <- c('Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria','Andorra','Angola','Antigua and Barbuda')
data <- c(NA, 8.53, 8.64, 21.25, 10.08, 9.07)

dF <- data.frame(country=country, data=data)

#join data to a map to create a spatialPolygonsDataFrame
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(dF, joinCode='NAME', nameJoinColumn='country')

#default map (see rworldmap documentation for options e.g. catMethod, numCats, colourPalette, mapRegion)
#missingCountryCol used for NA and countries not in the join file
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='data', missingCountryCol='dark grey')
```

[image: rworldmap plot]

Comment: Thanks for the tip dude! I already got the answer though, from using @mrip's advice and from using the rworldmap library. I'll post my code to show what I developed. I appreciate your time though and you are right about which code to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the code that I used to solve what I needed to do:

```
library(xlsx)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapproj)
library(mapdata)
library(rworldmap)
library(countrycode)

d <- read.xlsx("health_expenditure.xlsx",2)
d.df <- data.frame(d)
d.sub <- subset(d.df,Year=="2009")
w4 <- data.frame(d.sub$Country,data=d.sub$Numeric.Value)
colnames(w4)[1] <- "country"
w4$breaks <- cut(w4$data, 5)
w4$code <- countrycode(w4$country,"country.name","iso3c")
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(w4,joinCode="ISO3",nameJoinColumn="code")
par(mai=c(0,0,0.2,0),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
mapDevice()
mapCountryData(mapToPlot=sPDF, nameColumnToPlot="breaks",missingCountryCol="white",oceanCol="lightsteelblue2",colourPalette="heat",mapTitle="Health Expenditure")
```

[image: Health Expenditure in 2009]